# How to print text from a text file into pdf using fpdf and php

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to display the text from a text file into PDF using **FPDF** and PHP. I searched many links and tried the following code but I am not getting the output.

```
if(($FileType == 'txt'))
{    
   $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
   $this->write(10,file_get_contents(project/demo.txt));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying the `demo.txt` content on your PHP page ? Just to be sure you wrote the correct path

Comment: Yes, in php page it is working fine i have an issue with pdf only. how to display it in pdf? @AymDev

Comment: Are you looking for [`Output()`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) method ?

Comment: no i already done with other part $pdf = new PDF();
    `$pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage(); 
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
    for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
      $pdf->Cell(10,200,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
    $pdf->Output();

Comment: i want to display text from text file into pdf usinf fpdf

Comment: everything looks fine from here (except your extra parentheses in the condition). Change `$this` to `$pdf` ?

Comment: i tried it too but not working is there any issue with condition other than extra paranthesis()? @AymDev

Comment: How is `$FileType` set ?

Comment: by opening directory and reading the directory contents i am checking the condition and the same thing i am displaying in php page and that one is working fine. i am getting problem in pdf itself

Comment: I am getting the contents could you please tell me how to print line by line in pdf i am printing like this $fh = fopen("projects/1.txt", 'r'); $pageText = fread($fh, 25000); $this->Cell( 200, 60, nl2br($pageText), 0, 0, 'R' ); here nl2br is showing <br/> directly how to print the content line by line as it is in the txt file??

Comment: Don't use `nl2br` you don't need it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178414/discussion-between-user7628723-and-aymdev).